# Getting Drag and Drop to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I have been Googling for days now searching for javascript to have drag & drop functionality on my page. They all have the same result the items will not drag. Below is the current code I am trying currently.

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Coder2CoderMaster2.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TESTONLY.aspx.vb" Inherits="TESTONLY" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="head">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/Images/favicon2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="phBody">

 <div class="target">
    <asp:Image ID="pointer1" draggable="true" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/pointer1.png" />
    <asp:Image ID="pointer2" draggable="true" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/pointer2.png" />
 </div>
<br />
 <div id="drop_target-one">
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/1/1_20151019114033223_1.tif" />
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var dropZoneOne = document.querySelector('#drop-target-one');
     var dragElements = document.getElementsByClassName("target")[0];
     var elementDragged = null;

     for (var i = 0; i < dragElements.length; i++) {
         dragElements[i].addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
             e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
             elementDragged = this;
         });
         dragElements[i].addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
             elementDragged = null;
         });
     };
     dropZoneOne.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
        if (e.prevenDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'
        return false:
    });
    dropZoneONe.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
        this.className = "over"
    });
    dropZoneONe.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
        this.className = "";
    });
    dropZoneOne.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        this.className=""
        document.querySelector('#drag-elements').removeChild(elementDragged);
        return false;
    });
 </script>
 </asp:Content>
```

When I run this after uploading to GoDaddy, everything appears to display properly, but the pointer images will not drag, I get a "no" icon (slashed circle)
I want to be able to drag the pointer image on to the Image1 and drop it.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: For the record, you host has absolutely nothing to do with how your browser behaves.

Comment: Are you using jQuery-UI? If not, you might want to try it; it makes a lot of these types of things easier.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon using jQuery would be very sad when drag-and-drop is literally [supported in every major browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop)

Comment: Just about everything is supported in every major browsr; that doesn't make jQuery "sad." Just because you can walk from here to New York doesn't mean taking a jet would be "sad."

Comment: @B.ClayShannon what's that even supposed to mean. You're adding external dependencies to your code, increasing load time, ballooning memory usage for an feature that's already implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dropZoneONe`
`dropZoneOne`

You should really learn to use your browser's development tools to catch errors like this.

---

Also, script interpreter might ignore some things that may cause problems. You should add this line at the top of your scripts.

```
'use strict';
```

You can read more about [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

---

<strike>Quickly inspecting code suggests that there's `event.preventDefault()` missing in the `'dragenter'` event handler.</strike>

Comment: Typically F12 or a right click menu opens the development tools, and the Console tab is where to look for errors like this. You can also use the sources section to breakpoint/debug your code. It's worth spending some time and getting familiar with :)

Comment: SethWhite thank you I was not aware of that although it did not show the dropZoneONe problem

Comment: @SethWhite did the answer solve your issue? If so, you should mark it as correct using the checkmark next to the rating buttons, because of how SO works. Although, this is a rather low quality question and should not left up.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

try using this. just the simple drag and drop. also make sure that for the ids you want to drag, you do draggable=true and ondragstart=drop(event) this is the js